# Using ctx.lineTo when drawing projectiles won't work with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
function drawRocket(){
    ctx.lineTo(xx, yy);
    setTimeout(frame1, 1000);
}

function frame1(){
    ctx.lineTo(xx+50, yy+50);
    console.log("test");
}

drawRocket();
```

My main intention is drawing projectiles via ctx.lineTo on canvas to simulate rockets, the only problem is, whenever I use setInterval or setTimeout the line simply doesn't appear, console.log("test") does show up properly after timeout 1000 but the line doesn't work.

The line however does work when I put it on without a timeout, with timeout only the initial "ctx.lineTo(xx, yy)" draws a line, but "ctx.lineTo(xx+50, yy+50)" does not.

Putting both of these in one function that instantly draws them does work.

How can I fix it? Is it just not possible to delay line drawing on canvas?

Comment: lineTo just declares a path, to actually render it, you'll have to call ctx.stroke(). Also don't forget to call ctx.beginPath() before your path declaration, otherwise it will just add up to the previously declared path and you'll redraw these previous paths too.

Comment: Oh, that's what I was missing, the ctx.stroke. Thank you.